# I can no longer install android apps with apk

Tags: android

I recently created an android app. When I tried to debug my app on my phone, it worked. Then I generated the apk, and tried to execute it from the file browser, it doesn't work, and I have the following error message : "App not installed", despite having allowed the unknown source in the settings. I also tried with an official app. For that, I extracted the Apk with apk extractor, uninstalled the app, and then executed the apk: same error. I tried many solutions found on the web, but none of them worked :

- I disabled play protect.
- I reseted the app preferences in the settings.
- I tried on my former phone and on my father's phone.
- I updated the os on my phone (android 10 to android 12).

I have already installed many apps just by executing the apk on my phones (including my current one) and it's the first time i'm facing this problem.

Can you help me please ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. "Executing the apk on my phone" and "unknown sources" implies that the app was built with a third-party services and **not** with Android Studio. You should [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70318887/edit) your post with details as to what/how you are creating apps/debugging apps.

Comment: I executed the apk from the file browser, I have often done it, but this is the first time it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Debug build and Release build have different signatures so before installing "release app" you should uninstall "debug app".

Also check expiration date of your release signature and make sure it is a valid signature.